# How to use Angular 4 pipe to get Time Zone

Tags: javascript, angular, pipe

Does anyone know how to get the timezone through a pipe on IE? I've learned that pipes are not that compatible in general with IE, but I saw a fix on here to get the time and date by breaking it into separate pipes.

So instead of this:

```
{{dto?.someTime | date:'MMM.dd @ hh:mm a (Z)'}}
```

I had to change it to:

```
{{dto?.someTime | date:'MMM.dd @'}} {{dto?.someTime | date:'shortTime'}}{{dto?. someTime | date:'(Z)'}}
```

It now works in IE, and Edge, but the (Z) I used in the pipe, which normally displays the timezone, like CST or EST on Edge, Safari, and Chrome, is only showing 00 on IE. I'm trying to find a solution to do it through piping, without having to use momentjs. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just for confirmation. You have edited the pollyfills.ts file for date pipe right ?

Comment: I haven't, not sure if someone else on the project did or not. What would I edit or check?

Comment: Check the last section of pollyfills.ts:
// import 'intl';  // Run `npm install --save intl`.
run npm install and uncomment it.